# Magento product downloadable htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, magento

Hi i have a Magento site with downloadable product.

I'm using jPlayer script to allow user play mp3 audio but i want to protect them by htaccess.

This is my jPlayer code

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function (event) {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            //title: "Bubble",
            mp3: "<?php echo $link_audio; ?>",
            //m4a: "http://jplayer.org/audio/m4a/Miaow-07-Bubble.m4a",
        });
    },
    //swfPath: "../../dist/jplayer",
    supplied: "mp3",
    wmode: "window",
    useStateClassSkin: true,
    autoBlur: false,
    smoothPlayBar: true,
    keyEnabled: true,
    remainingDuration: true,
    toggleDuration: true
});
```

where link_audio is my magento/media/downloadable

So i want allow script execution but disallow browsing by web (like insert url).

I create this .htacces but doesn't work

```
Order allow, deny
Deny from all
```

Comment: It's a difficult problem. Even big sites like bandcamp have problem with this. You example is weaker though, since it lists the direct audio url in the page source. You can only make it harder to directly get your files.

Comment: i know it's weak. so i'm looking for a solution with htaccess or something else